# Any way in C++ to forward declare a function prototype?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

I make regular use of forward class declarations and pointers to such classes.

I now have a need to pass a function pointer through a number of layers. I would prefer to include the header that declares my function pointer's prototype only into the module that dereferences a function pointer rather than into each layer that simply passes along that pointer value.

Is this possible?

=====

From the replies I suspect that I have not expressed by question clearly enough.  I seek an analog to a forward class declaration. We all agree that I can write:

class foo;

void bar(foo*);

void waz(foo* p) { bar(p); }

Notice that waz knows nothing about class foo other than its name. Perhaps bar will have access to foo's complete description. Perhaps bar will simply pass p further along. Who cares? Only those sites that dereference a foo*. All other sites need only "class foo;".

Similarly I know that I can write:

typedef void foo(int, double);

void bar(foo*);

void waz(foo* p) { bar(p); }

The difference is that now the identifier foo not only is known to denote a function type but further already carries the full signature/prototype. This forces me into one of two unpleasant scenarios:

1) clone the typedef at multiple sites (yuck! fragile!)
2) stick the typedef in a header and include it everywhere that a foo* is mentioned.

Notice the asymetry: in the case of a data object I only needed to provide a complete description of class foo at those points where I want to dereference a foo*; in the case of a function I need to provide the full signature/prototype everywhere I want to mention a foo*.

So is there anyway to remedy this asymmetry?

Comment: There is no asymmetry. You can forward declare a class and a function, not a typedef. A typedef is just an alias, it doesn't exist any more at link time, so there is nothing to forward declare about it.

Comment: You argument is fallacious.  Yes, if used a function must exist at link time or you get an undefined symbol error.  OTOH a forward declared class does not.  Instances of such a class may exist but they are not what a forward declared class name denotes.  A forward declared class name denotes a class, not an object occupying storage.

Comment: "_A forward declared class name denotes a **[type]**, not an object occupying storage._" Just like a function pointer denotes a **type**, not a function occupying instructions (and an entry point) in the program. My point is that it is not about the `typedef`; that's irrelevant.

Comment: Also, it is much easier to write `void register(void (*callback)());` than `void foo(const std::unordered_map<std::vector<double>, std::string, CompanyName::FuzzyDoubleHash, CompanyName::FuzzyDoubleComparator>& bar);`. Nice symmetry, don't you think?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using an undefined structure type, at the cost of an extra dereference.

put this in the main header file:

```
typedef struct FuncStruct *FuncPtr;
```

This declares `struct FuncStruct` but does not declare any fields, then it declares a pointer to this struct called `FuncPtr`.  You can pass `FuncPtr`s around but you can not dereference them.

then in a particular file (or a more specific .h file), you can actually define a `struct FuncStruct` like this:

```
struct FuncStruct {
  int (*f)(int, char, double);
};
```

Then code past this definition can dereference a `FuncPtr` to get the actual function pointer.

Note this is an extra dereference from just a cast, and it means you'll need to do some memory management of `FuncStruct`s.

Answer (score 4):

For passing function pointers you only need to know the argument types and the return type:

```
void f(void (*func)(int));
```

Here, `f()` is a function that takes a function pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.

`typedef`s make that more readable:

```
typedef void (*FuncPtr)(int);
void f(FuncPtr func);
```

In general you might want to look at functors or using e.g. [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/function.html) and [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html). That way you can also pass in bound member functions or function objects:

```
void f(boost::function<void (int)> fn) {
    fn(42);
}

struct X {
    void f(int) {}
};

// ...
X x;
f(boost::bind(&X::f, &x, _1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, e.g.

```
typedef void (*FOOFUNC)(int x, int y, char z);
```

Now you can pass it around

```
void foo(FOOFUNC f) {
  f(...);
}
```

Comment: How is that a forward declaration ? That's a plain typedef, ain't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand exactly what the OP is trying to do.  In fact, I want to do the same thing. Following on what the OP said, I have the following (in C, not C++) :

```
/* File A.h */
typedef void (*f_t)(int x);

/* File B.h */
typedef void (*call_f_t)(f_t func2call,int y);
```

The question is, does `B.h` have to include `A.h`? `A.h`defines all sorts of other things I would rather not include in `B.h', so I am hoping is a way to "forward reference" a function pointer, without redefining it in a typedef in`B.h` (which probably doesn't even work)?

Or does the compiler need to know more about `f_t` in `B.h` than it would about, say, a forward referenced `struct`?

It is also possible that I need to rethink the layout of my code, but I agree with the OP, that in a perfect world, there should be some sort of symmetry between function pointers and other objects that can be forward-referenced.

Comment: You could use any function pointer in place of the actual function pointer, such as `void (*)()`. The standard guarantees that function pointers of any type are convertible to any other type.

Answer (score -1):

Totally possible. You can copy your function prototype wherever you need it, though when I see this done a lot, alarm bells start to go off.

Answer (score -2):

It is not clear from your question what you are tryng to do.

Firstly, there's no such thing as "prototype" in C++. The concept of "prototype" (function prototype) is specific to C language only.

Secondly, you mention some "function pointer's prototype" in the message body, while the caption talks about "function prototype". This makes it even more confusing. "Function pointer's prototype" makes no sense. There's no such thing as "prototype" for a pointer, even in C, let alone C++.

So, what is it you want to do? If you want to forward-declare a function - just declare it.

If you want to forward-declare a pointer - also just declare it. In order to obtain a declaration (a non-defining declaration) of an object, just declare it with an `extern` keyword.